# How to set the animated view in centre of the parent in android?

Tags: android, animation, scaletransform

I have total 5 image views in linear layout.first round it shows only 3 image views centre of the layout and second round first 3 image views are scale down or translate and visible the 4th image view and centre of the partent. and third round 4 views are scale down and visible the 5th image view in centre of the parent.

How to achive this in android using animations?

Answer (score 1):

Animations can be performed through either XML or android code. Here you get animation using xml.

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/

Hope it helps !